# What is the best way of updating a variable in a view controller from scene delegate?

Tags: swift

I am using Spotify SDK. I want to change labels in some view controllers when a user changes his/her player state. Here is my scene delegate:

```
var playerViewController = MatchViewController()

func playerStateDidChange(_ playerState: SPTAppRemotePlayerState) {
    playerViewController.stateChanged(playerState)
}
```

A view controller:

```
func stateChanged(_ playerState: SPTAppRemotePlayerState) {
    // aLabel.text = playerState.track.name
}
```

The problem is labels or other outlets are nil when the state is changed because the view controllers are not loaded at that time. How can I fix that? (I tried isViewLoaded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a more than a few places to update according to a change that occurs at one place use observers. Here's how,

Post notification in SceneDelegate like this:

```swift
func playerStateDidChange(_ playerState: SPTAppRemotePlayerState) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "stateChanged"), object: nil, userInfo: ["playerState": playerState])
}
```

Observe in ViewControllers like this:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(stateChanged), name: NSNotification.Name("stateChanged"), object: nil)
    }

    @objc func stateChanged(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let playerState = notification.userInfo?["playerState"] as? SPTAppRemotePlayerState {
            print(playerState)
        }
    }
}
```